# Return an object inside useEffect() and access it outside in React (after having assigned a state)

Tags: reactjs, loops, object, return, fetch

TLTR:

```
const ReturnPagination = () => {
    const [header, setHeader] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {

        let pageinitial = 1;
        fetch(config.taskRoute + '?page=' + pageinitial)
        .then(response => {

            var myvar = {
                res: response.json(),
                headers: response.headers.get('x-wp-totalPages')
            }
            console.log(myvar.headers);
            //will print the value that I need, in this case a number
            return lello;
        } )
        .then(setHeader)

        .catch(console.error)

    }, []);
    console.log(header.headers);
    //will display an error on the console

    if (header) {
        return (
            <Fragment>


            </Fragment>
            );

    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So in react is possible to access a variable and its sub-level (res/headers) inside the useEffect() function but it is not possible to access it outside it.

It is possible though to access the entire variable outside the useEffect function, right after push the state into that, but if I try to access a sub level (for example header.headers) the console will print the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'res' of null
```

Why my variable is null? Is it a bug?

The problem:

Here's my component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Fragment = React.Fragment;

const rootURL = 'mywordpress';

const config = {
    rootURL: rootURL,
    taskRoute: `${rootURL}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`,
};

const ReturnWordpress = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [header, setHeader] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(config.taskRoute)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        } )
        .then(setData)
        .catch(console.error)
        fetch(config.taskRoute)
        .then(res => {
            return res.headers.get('x-wp-total')
        } )
        .then(setHeader)

    }, []);
    //console.log(data, header);
    if (data) {
        return (
            <Fragment>
            {data.map((content, i) => {
                return(
                    <div className='col-md-6' key={i}>
                    <h1>{content.title.rendered}</h1>
                    <div
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                        __html: content.excerpt.rendered
                    }}></div>
                    <h4><a href={content.link}>Read more</a></h4>
                    </div>
                    );
            })}
            </Fragment>
            );

    } else {
        return null;
    }

}

export default ReturnWordpress;
```

And here's my problem. The idea is to extract an object from a fetch call in react. This code is working fine but it uses two fetch call. I would like to use only one fetch call and extract an object from that call in this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(config.taskRoute)
    .then(response => {
        return {
            res: response.json(),
            headers: res.headers.get('x-wp-total')
        } 
    } )
    .then(setData)
    .catch(console.error)
}, []);
console.log(data);
```

This snippet is going to work just fine too until the point where I will try to access the object, for example in this way = data.res. Actually I'm not even sure it is an object, but in any case, if I will try to access it as an array (data[res]) is not gonna work either.

Let's say that I will try to loop though the object before I will render it in a component, something like this:

```
for (const property in data) {
    console.log(`${property}: ${data[property]}`);
}
```

I will still not be able to access the property res of the object, because it will return res: [object Promise].

Another problem that I have with react is that is very hard to debug piece of code like that, because the console won't point the error, and I can't even console log the some level down of the object because something like data.header or data.res will make it break my stack.

I'm pretty sure that the solution is very simple, but at this moment I have no clue on how I can solve the enigma. Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use Jquery's $.when (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Another way to do this is using Promise.all()

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42;
const promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

Then in order to use this promise

```
create a function with the promise

async function example(){
return Promise.all([...]).then(function(values){
resolve(whatever)
})
})


function mainFunction(){
const responseValue = await example();
console.log("Do something with response value");

}



}
```

I'm not 100% sure I have this syntax right but I think it's what you're looking for. Just google search javascript await and use async functions since it takes time for the promise to be resolved

Comment: I want to use fetch, that's the best approach, with jquery I should need to add a module only for jquery

Comment: What about Promise.all() ?

Comment: That would be good, but ideally I would use fetch instead

Comment: To be honest, that's a good approach too, but ideally I would love to figure it out how to use a simple fetch api

Comment: The only this is now how to access the variable outside of the promise?

Comment: Updated my answer to show this if it's still relevant